# How to distinguish tablets form mobile phones by HTTP_USER_AGENT

Tags: php, html, user-agent

There are different approaches to detect portable devices such as tablets and mobile phones using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. Are there  general rules for us to distinguish tablets from mobile phones ?

Comment: You can do your own way with regex or use something which already exist, for instance [Detect Mobile](http://mobiledetect.net/). (`$device->isMobile()`)

Comment: "Mobile Detect is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices (including tablets)" - read the question title

Comment: @user2818066 how would you distinguish if you had 2 in your hands? By screen size? By SIM card or WiFi?  The concept of Phablets would seem to render this question unanswerable, if not meaningless  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phablet